# Compiling a Linux application on OS X - not finding standard library (cmath)

Tags: c++, linux, macos, cmake, std

I'm attempting to build an application on OS X that was written on Linux, but I'm running into a slew of errors in a helper file. The helper is a wrapper on `cmath` of the form:

```
#include <cmath>

namespace [application name]
{   
  namespace math
  {
    template<typename T>
    inline T Log10(const T& x)
    {
      return T(log10(static_cast<double>(x)));
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm getting errors of the form:

```
/pathtofile/common/math/Helpers.t:132:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'log10'; did you mean 'Log10'?
  return T(log10(static_cast<double>(x)));
           ^
/pathtofile/common/math/Helpers.t:130:14: note: 'Log10' declared here
inline T Log10(const T& x)
```

I've done some research on this problem and someone on Stack Overflow said the following:

> I had this problem - it was driving me crazy but I tracked down the cause, and it was a little different than what I've seen reported on this issue.
>
> In this case, the general cmath header (or math.h - the error and solution occur in C++ or C) had architectural environment switches to include architecture specific math subheaders. The architecture switch (environment variable) hadn't been defined, so it was punting and not actually including the headers that truly defined the math functions.
>
> So there was indeed a single math.h or cmath.h, and it was included, but that wasn't enough to get the math functions. In my case, rather than define the architectural variable, I instead found the location of the correct sub math headers and added them to my compile path. Then the project worked!
>
> This seems to be an issue that comes up a lot when porting Linux projects to OS-X. I'd imagine it might occur anytime a project was moved between platforms such that the standard library headers are arranged differently.

Is this the problem? If so, how do I solve this (I'm not sure how to follow his advice)?

Edit: If I reference the math functions by namespace std, I get the following:

```
/pathtofile/common/math/Helpers.t:62:14: error: no member named 'acos' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'ACos'?
  return std::acos(x);
         ^~~~~
/pathtofile/common/math/Helpers.t:60:14: note: 'ACos' declared here
inline T ACos(const T& x)
```

Edit2: If it's relevant, I'm attempting to build this project with cmake 3.0. The code itself runs fine in isolation, so the problem would seem to be elsewhere.

Comment: The standard library functions are in the `std` namespace. So you need to call `std::log10`.

Comment: @CodyGray That was my first thought as well, I've edited the OP to reflect my results for that change.

Comment: `#include <cmath>

namespace math
{
template<typename T>
inline T Log10(const T& x)
{
 return T(log10(static_cast<double>(x)));
}
} // math

int main()
{
 auto t = math::Log10(10);
 return 0;
}` this seems to compile fine for me on OSX 10.11, what version are you compiling on? did you specify any compilation -std?

Comment: @kirinthos 10.11. Interestingly, your code snippet compiles for me as well (in a separate test file). This application uses `cmake`, with which I have zero experience. Could there be something wrong with that setup?

Comment: most definitely, could you perhaps post some of that -- edit: what can happen pretty commonly on OSX cmake files is the OSX sdk resolution stuffs, are you generating an Xcode project? you could open the project and check the build settings of the project to begin isolating where it's including headers from and maybe find out why the proper headers aren't being included

Comment: @kirinthos I'm not generating an Xcode project, so unfortunately that debug information isn't readily available. Which cmake files would be most helpful to post? The setup process populated an entire build folder.

Comment: compiles fine for me on OSX and linux. what version of OSX? What's the command line?

Comment: @RichardHodges 10.11, shell is zsh. The current theory is that this is a problem with `cmake`; the code compiles in isolation for me, too.

Comment: it's always a mistake to start giving cmake custom compiler settings in the actual cmake script. It interferes with the proper deduction of the environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't write this software. I don't have much experience with cmake, is there something in particular I should look for in the script or is this problem unsolvable?

Comment: cd <bindir> && rm CMakeCache.txt && cmake -GXcode ../src_dir  (case sensitive). Then open the .xcodeproj file. Xcode will allow you to easily see which include paths have been selected. It'll be something horribly non-standard and non-portable in the cmake file(s)

Comment: @RichardHodges Xcode shows the following under Header Search Paths: Debug, MinSizeRel, RelWithDebInfo, and Release. Sorry if that's irrelevant - haven't really used Xcode much. I'm thinking of running Linux in a VM for this project, so if there's no clear answer don't sweat it. I'd prefer to run this on in macOS, though, so any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat > chk.cpp
#include <cmath>

namespace app
{
    namespace math
    {
        template<typename T>
        inline T Log10(const T& x)
        {
            return T(log10(static_cast<double>(x)));
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    return app::math::Log10(100.0);
}
$ c++ -std=c++14 chk.cpp
$ ./a.out
$ echo $?
2
```

I don't think the problem is here.

Comment: I think you're correct. I suspect the problem is somehow with cmake. Can you think of a way that cmake might have this issue building a linux application for OS X? Is there any make code I can post that would help?

Comment: the smallest cmake file that replicates the problem? something small enough for me to run through cmake here?

Comment: i.e. 1 source file, 1 cmake script file. all libraries etc stripped away